# My function isnt taking a string when its suppossed to

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to have my `Actor` function work. However
when I input a `string` into the parameter I get these errors

`Line 100: error: cannot convert ‘Vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ to ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’`

`Line 100: Actors.push_back((split(actorData, "\t")));`
`Line 118: error: no match for call to ‘(Vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >) (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)’`

`Line 118: Actors = Actor(ActorData[3]);`

[vector.h](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/StanfordCPPLib/doc/Vector-class.html) library

> Vector.h is practically the same as the standard **vector** class

[txtfile](https://easyupload.io/kq8wo7)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "vector.h" //You can also use <vector>

using namespace std;



Vector<string> split (string s, string delimiter)
{
  size_t pos_start = 0, pos_end, delim_len = delimiter.length();
  string token;
  Vector<string> res;

  while ((pos_end = s.find (delimiter, pos_start)) != string::npos)
  {
    token = s.substr (pos_start, pos_end - pos_start);
    pos_start = pos_end + delim_len;
    res.push_back (token);
  }

  res.push_back (s.substr (pos_start));
  return res;
}
/*
  movie Data
    - returns data from the txt file and stores them in a vector
  Returns:
    - a vector with movie names and actors
*/
Vector<string> movieData(string &filename)
{
  fstream myFile;
  Vector<string> data;
  string content; //All the content casts and movie title
  myFile.open(filename);
  if(!myFile.good()) //If the file failed
  {
    cout << "File Not Found" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  //---------------------------------------
  while(getline(myFile, content, '\n')) //seperates each movie by the line
  {
    data.push_back(content);
  }
  //---------------------------------------
  myFile.close();
  return data;
}
/*
  movie Title
    - a Vector with Movie Titles
  Returns:
    - a Vector only including the movie titles from each
      distinct line
*/
Vector<string> movieTitle(Vector<string> &data)
{
  Vector<string> Titles;
  for(int i = 0; i<data.size(); i++)
  {
    int pos = data[i].find("\t");
    Titles.push_back(data[i].substr(0, pos));
  }
  return Titles;
}

/*
  actor Data
    - a Vector with the Actors that are unsliced
      ex: Oscar Issac\tEthan Hawke
  Returns:
    - a Vector only including the actors and not the title
      from each distinct line
*/
Vector<string> actorData(Vector<string> &data)
{
  Vector<string> actorData;
  string word;
  for(int i = 0; i<data.size(); i++)
  {
    int pos = data[i].find(')');
    data[i].erase(0, pos+2);
    actorData.push_back(data[i].substr(0, data[i].length()-1));
  }
  return actorData;
}
/*
  Actor
    - a Vector with the Actors that are sliced
  Returns:
    - a Vector only including the actors and not the title
      from each distinct line
*/
Vector<string> Actor(string &actorData)
{
  Vector<string> Actors;
  Actors.push_back((split(actorData, "\t"))); //Trying to remove tab from the
  return Actors;                               //previous vector
}

int main()
{
  Vector<string> data; //contains titles and cast seperated by \t
                      //ex: Moon Knight (2022)\tOscar Issac\tEthan Hawke
  Vector<string> Title; //Contains Just the Title
                        //ex: Moon Knight (2022)
  Vector<string> ActorData; //Contais the cast that are unscliced
                            //ex: Oscar Issac\tEthan Hawke
  Vector<string> Actor; //contains the actors that are sliced
                        //ex: "Oscar Issac", "Ethan Hawke"
  string filename = "movies_mpaa.txt";
  data = movieData(filename);
  Title = movieTitle(data);
  ActorData = actorData(data);
  Actors = Actor(ActorData[3]);
  //-------------------------------//
  cout << "The Cast Of: "<< Title[3] << " is:" << endl;
  cout << "Actor: " << Actors << endl;
  //cout << "//--------------------//" << endl;
  //cout << "Data: " << data[2] << endl;


  return 0;
}
```

I used the debugger and something is wrong within  my `Actor` function, but how come? Everything should be fine since it logically makes sense.

- `Actor` accepts a string
- `ActorData` is a vector with strings inside
- `Actor(ActorData[3])` should work
- The `split` function is also good because it just splices strings

Comment: “Practically the same” means they aren’t, in fact, the same

Comment: Compiler is confused, because you have `Actor` function and `Actor` variable. Avoid using the same names for different things.

Comment: Which lines are 100 and 118?

Comment: Line 100: `Actors.push_back((split(actorData, "\t"))); //Trying to remove tab`

Line 118: `Actors = Actor(ActorData[3]);`

Comment: This is because you're reusing the same name for the `Actor` function and the `Actor` vector. Names should be unique. Use some comment sense when choosing your variable names so that they don't conflict with other things that are in scope. Reading your code is horrific, because it's difficult to read when everything looks like it's named the same.

Comment: Your split function returns a vector, not a string. You’re trying to push a vector of strings into a vector of strings, perhaps you meant to append or apply?

Comment: Actually I think you meant to just return the results of split?

Comment: @KenWhite even if I change the name the problem still continues

Comment: @Taekahn I meant to store the result of split into the new vector

Comment: Yes, but either you need to return only a single string from split or you need to assign the return result to an existing vector or you need to just return the results of split. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign

Comment: Side note, if you included a text file that is 20MB, make sure to explain what it is for. If it is sample input, you probably want to reduce it to just a few entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this

```
Vector<string> Actor(string &actorData)
{
  Vector<string> Actors;
  Actors.push_back((split(actorData, "\t"))); //Trying to remove tab from the
  return Actors;                               //previous vector
}
```

splittig the code up a bit gives

```
Vector<string> Actor(string &actorData)
{
  Vector<string> Actors;
  Vector<string> splitStrs = split(actorData, "\t");
  Actors.push_back(splitStrs); //Trying to remove tab from the
  return Actors;                               //previous vector
}
```

You cannot push a vector of strings into a vector of strings. I suspect you want the first one (your comment says you are trying to remove a tab)

So you need

```
Actors.push_back(splitStrs[0]);
```

or maybe you mean to add them all

```
Actors.insert(Actors.begin(), splitStrs.begin(), stritStes.end());
```

Comment: Despite what OP said, this weird `Vector` is very much unlike `std::vector`. The easiest way would be to do just `return split(actorData, "\t");`, the other ways are super non-idiomatic.

Comment: Now Im getting an error within actorData for `line 86 actorDatas = (data[i].substr(0, data[i].length()-1));`
error: no matching function for call to ‘Vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::insert(Vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::iterator, Vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::iterator, Vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::iterator)’

Comment: @Yksisarvinen yup, I did not analyze exactly what was going on , rather just supressing the error

Comment: @Andyrew thats because I forgot you are not using std::vector  for some reason. Do as YK suggests just return the result of split

Comment: How about you test the changes with std::vector, @Andyrew

Comment: I fixed it. Dude @pm100 whoever you are I want to be like you.